# Jumping onto next string when the condition is met

Tags: c++, string

This was a problem related to one of the past topcoder exam problems called HowEasy.

Let's assume that we're given a sentence, for instance,

```
"We a1re really awe~~~some"
```

I just wanted to take get rid of every word in the sentence that doesn't contain alphabet characters, so in the above sentence, the desired output would be

```
 "We really"
```

The below is the code I wrote (incomplete), and I don't know how to move on to the next string when the condition (the string contains a character that's not alphabet) is met. Could you suggest some revisions or methods that would allow me to do that?

vect would be the vector of strings containing the desired output

```
string param;
cin>>param;

stringstream ss(param);
vector<string> vect;
string c;

while(ss >> c){

    for(int i=0; i < c.length(); i++){

        if(!(97<=int(c[i])&&int(c[i])<=122) &&
           !(65<=int(c[i])&&int(c[i])<=90)){

            //I want to jump onto next string once the above condition is met
           //and ignore string c;
        }
        vect.push_back(c);

        if (ss.peek() == ' '){
            ss.ignore();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using numbers instead of characters makes the code 10x less readable. Ignoring non-English letters, you should also use `std::isalpha` instead of reinventing it (in a way that does not always work, even for just English letters), and `std::none_of` or `std::any_of` instead of the loop. Also note that `ss >> c` discards leading whitespace, so the `peek` check is pointless.

Comment: Using a fat condition instead of a function does, too. Especially when we have [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) at hand.

Comment: Not the problem you mention, but I believe you want the `vect.push_back(c)` to be outside the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new function that checks if the whole string is a letter. Then you don't have this problem:

```
bool only_letters( std::string str )
{
    for( const char& c : str )
    {
       if( !std::isalpha( c ) )
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// ...
while( ss >> c )
{
     if( only_letters( c ) )
     {
         vect.push_back(c);
         if( ss.peek() == ' ' )
             ss.ignore();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a Standard Library only (c++11) solution, here you go :

- Use `std::istream_iterator` to iterate the words of your string
- Use `std::copy_if` to conditionally place words in your vector
- The condition is a lambda checking with `std::find_if` for the non existence of non-alpha characters

**Code:**

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "We a1re really awe~~~some";
    std::istringstream str(s);
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    
    std::copy_if(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(str), 
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::back_inserter(v),
        [](const std::string& sp) { return std::find_if(std::begin(sp), std::end(sp), [](char c) { return !std::isalpha(c); } ) == std::end(sp); } 
        );
    
    for(auto& w : v)
       std::cout << w << "\n";    
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output :**

> We
>
> really

---

**[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb1a0c44f42723ab)**

Answer (score 1):

This is a heavy-handed way of handling it, but you can use `algorithm` and `cctype` to achieve what you want. Note that the code assumes that you literally want the output `We really` rather than storing `We` and `really` separately into a vector (this captures the space after really, though.) The code can be modified to fit the latter by removing `find_space + 1` and `std::isspace(c)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "We a1re really awe~~~some";

    auto word_begin = s.begin();
    auto find_space = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), ' ');
    std::string result = "";
    while (find_space != s.end())
    {
        std::string word(word_begin, find_space + 1);

        if (std::none_of(word.begin(), word.end(), 
             [](char c) { return !(std::isalpha(c) || std::isspace(c)); }))
        {
            result += word;
        }

        word_begin = find_space + 1;
        find_space = std::find(word_begin, s.end(), ' ');
    }
    std::cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```